# PHP get key value OR max lower

Tags: php, arrays

I'v got this array:

```
$by_date = array(
    "2018-10-05"=>54,
    "2018-10-07"=>20,
    "2018-10-08"=>31,
    "2018-10-12"=>52
    );
```

I want to get value by date, but if the date doesn't exist get the lowest date value

for example:

if the date is "`2018-10-07`" I'll get **20**

and if the date is "`2018-10-10`" I'll get **31**

that can go to bigger differences between the date and the last key in the array

For example, if the date is "`2019-01-25`" I'll get **52** because "`2018-10-12`" is **the last key** in the array.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I think You are getting downvotes because you have not shared your tried code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it with a simple if condition that uses [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check for your input as a key on the array.  If the condition is met, you return the matched value, otherwise, use [max()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) and [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to return the value with the highest key.

```
$by_date = array(
    "2018-10-05"=>54,
    "2018-10-07"=>20,
    "2018-10-08"=>31,
    "2018-10-12"=>52
    );

$testVal = '2018-10-12'

if (isset($by_date[$testVal]))
    return $by_date[$testVal];
else 
    return $by_date[max(array_keys($by_date))];
```

Comment: will `min` work with dates, If in case works then this would give lowest in array not in lower then given date which will be wrong by OP's statement.

Comment: `array_key_exists` would be better to check for the key

Comment: This is stored as a key, it won't be in datetime format

Comment: are you getting output as `"2015-10-08"=>31` for date `2018-10-09` or ``2018-10-10``

Comment: The array's value would be `31` for the key `2018-10-08`.  The lowest key is `2018-10-05`, so that would be the output for `2018-10-10`, or any other that isn't found as a key in the array.

Comment: Check [this Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/276dfae205199a6f4f7d29651ceeb0e2fc8bd8a7) You are getting `52` instead `31`  as OP  said `and if the date is "2018-10-10" I'll get 31`

Comment: By the way you are very lucky , OP asked 8 question and first time he accepted others answer.

Answer (score 0):

You guys where right the previews answer wasn't good enough
I'v made a work around that works for me, not sure about efficiency

```
if (!isset($by_date[$testVal])){
    $by_date[$testVal] = null;
    ksort($by_date);
    $date_key = array_search($price_date,array_keys($by_date));
    $by_date[$testVal] = (array_values($by_date)[$date_key-1]);
}

$by_date_price =  $by_date[$testVal];
```

Thank you for the help and comments